# 403 Forbidden ffmpeg / youtube-dl

Tags: video, browser, ffmpeg, blob, youtube-dl

I am trying to download a blob video that is playing in my browser:

```
 ffmpeg -i 'https://example.com/playlist.m3u8?cred=abcd' -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \              
    -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 file.mp4
```

I get the error

> https @ 0x11fe2ade0] HTTP error 403 Forbidden [hls @ 0x11fe05610]
> Failed to open an initialization section in playlist 0
> Error when loading first segment
> 'https://example.com/s2q1.m4s'

Indeed, when I open `https://example.com/s2q1.m4s` I get 403 forbidden in browser. However, if I add `https://example.com/s2q1.m4s?cred=abcd` , I get no error.

I get the same behaviour with `youtube-dl`

So how to make `ffmpeg` or `youtube-dl` append whatever query parameter in the input url in all subsequent requests ?